# Differential privacy basics: Universe \mathcal{X} and database $x$

Tags: differential-privacy

The "Algorithmic Foundations of Differential Privacy" book (DOI: 10.1561/0400000042) introduces formally the "universe" and "database" on page 17 roughly as:

- $\mathcal{X}$ is a universe
- databases $x$ are collections of records from the universe
- For convenience, we use histogram of types from the universe $\mathcal{X}$ to represent $x$, such that: $x \in \mathbb{N}^{|\mathcal{X}|}$ where each entry $x_i$ represents the number of elements in the database $x$ of type $i \in \mathcal{X}$

If you take the example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy#The_Laplace_mechanism)

[image: Table]

- The universe $\mathcal{X}$ is a set $\{0, 1\}$?
- The database $x$ is

  - a vector `[3, 3]` (assuming the universe is ordered)?
  - or a map `{0:3, 1:3}`?

My two questions are:

- Is my understanding correct?
- Why is it "convenient" to do so? What would be the non-convenient alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little late. Your understanding seems correct. $\mathcal{X}=Names \times \{0,1\}$ Where $Names$ are all the possible names that could exist and $x \in \mathbb{N}^{2}$ (Because of $|\mathcal{X}|=2$).

Then you can choose one column and select the histogram of the type you want. Then you can express $x=(x_0,x_1)=(3,3)$ or $x=(x_{ross},...,x_{Rachel})=(1,..,1)$. A you see the first one is more convenient.